# Add syminfo.currency and syminfo.basecurrency to 3commas webhook message?

Tags: pine-script, webhooks, pine-script-v5

I  am setting up my webhook alert message and i am wondering if there is a way to add in the currency and basecurrency.
I have tried it the following way but the problem is that it needs to be in quotation marks for 3commas to read it properly and if i do that then the message will just have '  + syminfo.currency + "_" + syminfo.basecurrency +  ' as the text.
The first version is the way it needs to be but i have to manually modify the code for each different pair that im setting the alert on and i have different scenarios for both buy and sell alerts. Would currently take me a day to reset them if i make any changes to my script.

```
alert('{  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": XXXXXX,  "email_token": "XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "pair": "USDT_BTC" }', freq = alertFreq)

alert('{  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": XXXXXX,  "email_token": "XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "pair": '  + syminfo.currency + "_" + syminfo.basecurrency +  ' }', freq = alertFreq)
```

I am trying to do this so that as soon as i change the pair on the chart and select set Alert on my indicator it will automatically fill in the correct info.

I worked out how to get the underscore in the middle, but when i try to put a single quotation mark inside a pair of quotation marks it all goes wrong . Is there a way to add the quotation marks to it without it turning the syminfo requests into a quote themselves.
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `"` before and after the single quotes around the currency pair.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

str = '{  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": XXXXXX,  "email_token": "XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXX",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "pair": "'  + syminfo.currency + "_" + syminfo.basecurrency +  '" }'

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: Absolute Legend, Thankyou very much, once again you have saved me hours of going around in circles.   Im still learning but getting there :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it for pairs like AAVEUSDT.3L on Kucoin.  I cant work out how to get the 3L 3S etc attached to the basecurrency.  It seems to just remove it as its after the base in the ticker or tickerid